# what is the significant of Business Netwrok Card in fabric composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Recently I have observed that we would have to use Card in order to create identity.

I have following following link, but still not able to understand what additional advantages or benefits we are getting out of Business Network Card.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//playground/id-cards-playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Business Network Card provides the means to connect to a Composer business network which runs in a Composer runtime container. It is only possible to access a Composer business network through a valid Business Network Card. It consists of a connection profile, some metadata for the identity using it, and ultimately, a set of credentials (certificate/private key). An identity can have one or more cards, to connect to one or more business networks.

The benefits are that once you export a card, it is a portable card to connect to the Composer business network running on the blockchain network, so can be issued/given to someone (usually that real identity in that Organisation) to then transact on business network, on the blockchain network.

See here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/participantsandidentities.html . An identity maps to a signed identity issued by the CA server (configured as a node or set of nodes that are part of the Fabric / blockchain network). Composer can register/request these identities, but to interact with a Composer business network, that identity must be mapped to a participant defined in Composer.  The identity (ie ultimately its set of credentials) is a constituent part of a Composer business network card - the card also includes connection information (how to connect to the blockchain network), info about the business network its used with (eg. `trade-network`), and some metadata about the identity itself. Cards once generated, are imported into the user's card store/wallet. From there, that identity can interact (by using the card) as a participant, with the business network, and generate transactions signed by his/her certificate.

Comment: Thank You Paul,

I am confused to understand what is difference between Business Network Card and Identity?

- composer card

- composer identity

Comment: the explanation is in the answer above.

Comment: Thank You Paul for detail explanation.